# JPA Criteria select from some tables

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, criteria

There are the following structure of tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Train
(
    idTrain INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nameTrain CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (idTrain)
);

CREATE TABLE Station
(
    idStation INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nameStation CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (idStation)
);

CREATE TABLE Schedule
(
    idStation INT NOT NULL,
    idTrain INT NOT NULL,
    arrivalTime TIME NOT NULL,
    departureTime TIME NOT NULL,
    nextStation INT NOT NULL,
    kmToNextStation INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (idStation, idTrain, nextStation),
    FOREIGN KEY (idStation) REFERENCES Station(idStation),
    FOREIGN KEY (idTrain) REFERENCES Train(idTrain),
    FOREIGN KEY (nextStation) REFERENCES Station(idStation)
);
```

Necessary to implement the following sql-query using JPA Criteria:

```
SELECT Station.nameStation, Schedule.arrivalTime, Schedule.departureTime, Schedule.kmToNextStation
FROM Schedule
JOIN Station
    ON Station.idStation = Schedule.idStation
JOIN Train
    ON Schedule.idTrain = Train.idTrain
WHERE Train.nameTrain = "268A";
```

Here is my attempt:

```
EntityManager em = EntitySupport.getEntityManager();
        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<ScheduleEntity> cq = builder.createQuery(ScheduleEntity.class);
        Root<ScheduleEntity> root = cq.from(ScheduleEntity.class);
        Join<ScheduleEntity, TrainEntity> idTrain = root.join("idTrain");
        Join<ScheduleEntity, StationEntity> idStation = root.join("idStation");
        cq.multiselect(root.get("arrivalTime"),
                root.get("departureTime"),
                idTrain.get("nameTrain"));
        Query query = em.createQuery(cq);
        List res = query.getResultList();
        System.out.println("Result query: " + res.toString());
```

Apparently, I'm doing something wrong, because I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate
>   appropriate constructor on class [srt.entity.ScheduleEntity]. Expected
>   arguments are: java.util.Date, java.util.Date, java.lang.String
>   [select new srt.entity.ScheduleEntity(generatedAlias0.arrivalTime,
>   generatedAlias0.departureTime, generatedAlias1.nameTrain) from
>   srt.entity.ScheduleEntity as generatedAlias0 inner join
>   generatedAlias0.idTrain as generatedAlias1 inner join
>   generatedAlias0.idStation as generatedAlias2]

Help me make the correct code for the above sql-query using JPA Criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong in the concept of JPA Criteria. Now I completely understood, the answer would be as follows:

```
EntityManager em = EntitySupport.getEntityManager();
        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<ScheduleEntity> cq = builder.createQuery(ScheduleEntity.class);
        Root<ScheduleEntity> from = cq.from(ScheduleEntity.class);
        Join<ScheduleEntity, StationEntity> idStation = from.join("idStation");
        Join<ScheduleEntity, TrainEntity> idTrain = from.join("idTrain");
        Predicate where = builder.equal(idTrain.get("nameTrain"), "268A");
        cq.where(where);
        List<ScheduleEntity> schedule = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
        for(ScheduleEntity s : schedule) {
            System.out.println(s.toString());
        }
```